# custom report through python odoo 9

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-9

How to pass multiple module data to a QWeb report? Is there something similar to passing dictionary in rendering html from controller?

```py
class account(model.Models):
    _name = 'account.main'      

    name = fields.Char()


class accountSub(model.Models):
    _name = 'account.sub'

    name = fields.Char()    

class PrintWizard(model.Models):
    _name = 'print.report'


    account = fields.Many2one('erp.account')

    @api.multi
    def print_report(self):
       ctx = self.env.context.copy()
       ctx.update({'domain':[('name','=',self.account.name)]})
       self.with_context(ctx)
       return {'name': 'Report',
            'type': 'ir.actions.report.xml',
            'report_name': 'erp.report_id',
            'report_type': 'qweb-pdf'}


class ErpReport(models.AbstractModel):
   _name = "report.erp.report_id"

   @api.multi
   def print_report(self)
       domain = self.env.context.get('domain')
       print(domain) #Print result was None
       main = self.env['account.main'].search(domain)
       sub = self.env['account.sub'].search([])
       docs = {
          'docs1': main,
          'docs2': sub,
       }
       return self.env['report'].render('erp.report', docs)
```

QWeb

```xml
<report
    id="report_id"
    string="Report"
    model="erp.report"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    file="erp.report"
    name="erp.report"
/>

<template id="payment_slip">
    <t t-call="nationalerp_sales.erp_external_layout">
        <t t-call="report.html_container">
            <div class="page">
                <div>
                    <t t-foreach="docs1" t-as="main">
                        <t t-esc="main.name"/>
                    </t>
                    <t t-foreach="docs2" t-as="sub">
                        <t t-esc="sub.name"/>
                    </t>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Passing data through context is not working. i tried to print the domain in abstract class it return none. but in my wizard it's okay

Comment: Do you have full example of this report, Can you send me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run specific code before your report prints or pass custom data to your template for rendering you can create an Abstract model which defines a `render_html` function so that your function will run when printing the report rather than the generic odoo function. This is referenced in the documentation 
[HERE](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html#custom-reports)

Take a look at this example.

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, exceptions

class YourReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.your_addon.report_template_id'

    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('your_addon.report_template_id')
        model1_docs = self.env['your_addon.your_model1'].search([('something','=','something')])
        model2_docs = self.env['your_addon.your_model2'].search([('something','=','something')])   
        docargs = {
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'model1_docs': model1_docs,
            'model2_docs': model2_docs,
        }
        return report_obj.render('your_addon.report_template_id', docargs)
```

UPDATE WITH MODIFIED CONTEXT:

To call your report with a modified context try the following (untested). I could not find any examples of calling reports with modified context however did not look extensively.

```
ctx = self.env.context.copy()
ctx.update({'domain':[('something','=','something')]})
self.with_context(ctx)
return {
    'name':'Report',
    'type':'ir.actions.report.xml,
    'report_name':'your_addon.report_template_id',
    'report_type':'qweb-pdf'
}
```

Then from within your report function we defined earlier you should be able to access context through your environment.

```
domain = self.env.context.get('domain')
```

You will need to create a function in your wizard which calls the report passing the context.

Comment: how to pass domain to model2_docs and model1_docs search from a wizard. i tried create method but didn't worked

Comment: You will have to post your code to determine the reason. It could be anything. I have not seen passing a custom context with a report.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to create a custom Model report which is wrapped on v9 API. Creating custom object report is three step process

1. Create RML Prase Custom Report Object
2. Wrap RML Report to AbstractModel Report for qweb engine.
3. Design template for the custom object.
4. Register your under report registry.

### **All Four Part listed here with possible sample code.**

**RML Prase Custom Report Object**

```
import time
from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp.report import report_sxw


class CustomReportPrint(report_sxw.rml_parse):

    def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
        super(CustomReportPrint, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            'lst': self._lst,
            'total': self._some_total,
            'get_records':self._get_records,
        })

    def _get_records(self, res_ids):
        records = self.pool.get('res.partner').browse(self.cr, self.uid, res_ids)
        return records

    def _lst(self, employee_id, dt_from, dt_to, max, *args):
        #Your code goes here
        return res

    def _some_total(self, employee_id, dt_from, dt_to, max, *args):
        #Your code goes here
        return [result_dict]
```

**Wrapping** RML Prase Object tot he QWeb Engine.

```
class report_custom_print(osv.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.<module_name>.report_custom_print'
    _inherit = 'report.abstract_report'
    _template = '<module_name>.report_custom_print'
    _wrapped_report_class = CustomReportPrint
```

**Report XML look as below** as you can see I am calling `get_records` from custom report model.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="report_custom_print">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="get_records(data['form']['res_ids'])" t-as="employee">
                    <t t-call="report.internal_layout">
                        <div class="page">
                            <div class="oe_structure" />
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**Registering Report**

```
    <record id="action_report_custom_print" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
        <field name="name">Custom Print Report</field>
        <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="report_name"><module_name>.report_custom_print</field>
        <field name="report_file"><module_name>.report_custom_print</field>
    </record>
```

In custom Rml report Object you can define as many functions as you like and register them under `__int__` and you can call those function directly on yor rpeort and mutpllate data as you need.

PS: replace  with your module to make wit works correct.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Nice answer, but why should somebody use deprecated RML reports in Odoo 9 anymore?

Comment: First things I would have mention here is what version are you using ? You question suggesting v9 or higher. Now is just 20% migrated and still holding most of old code and unfortunately v9 has only this way of handling it . If you are asking v10 the yes code would change to certain extend. Avian v9 in-between old and new API . Also we see not using old parse just using report class that hold rml parse name. Carefully running through code would suggest you we are writing qweb only. Same code in v10 would change over little.

Comment: First it is not my question and second his example report xml entry states clearly type="qweb-pdf".

Comment: I update my question please kindly check the report has been printed by context is not passed.

Comment: @JediShadow Is there an example of this is explained in more detail for beginners?