# Generate qweb report odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, qweb

Is it possible to display a search sql statement output in QWEB report?

In popup I want add field date, quanatity after choose date and quantity on button click call "SELECT * FROM 123 WHERE date = field date AND quantity = field quantity.

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

For this you have to extend create a model that the template uses to fetch data and override the `render_html` method.

For an example of this take a look at `addons/account_extra_reports/report/account_journal.py` The `docargs` are the variables that will be available to you inside the template to use. See the `_get_taxes` method that performs and sql query and formats the data accordingly.

Comment: Tnx for help but that example is very complicated for me.

Comment: Well if you want to override the middle layer (ORM) between the qweb and the sql things will get complicated. Is there any particular reason you do not want to use Odoo's ORM?

Comment: I need custom report something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290627/custom-report-through-python-odoo-9  something easy to figure out how it works on etc res.users, with any parameter from wizard.