# Create custom report odoo 9

Tags: python, report, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I'm new in odoo. I need one custom report but don't understand all about this.

In odoo documentation stay:

```
from openerp import api, models

class ParticularReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.module.report_name'

    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('module.report_name')
        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': self._ids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': self,
        }
        return report_obj.render('module.report_name', docargs)
```

I want from `res.users` in `qweb` display all user and field (create_date, name, descrption) what do I need to change in above example and how do I create view?

Any similar examples for a beginner?

Comment: Take a look at my existing answer. It might have the information you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290627/custom-report-through-python-odoo-9/40291820#40291820

Comment: @PhillipStack Thanks for replay, In your example I don't see view (with field) and how call render_html

Comment: When you have properly registered your report Odoo will call that method for you. Are you just trying to call your report using the more drop down? I am expanding an answer for you right now. Give me a moment.

Comment: @PhillipStack What is (_get_report_from_name, your_model1, your_model2) any descripion? Can you describe how create view (report_name) and how add foreach loop?

Comment: I will take a look at this later. I am sorry. I have some work to do at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at my previous answer you can see how you define a custom report for your model. The important part is that you find the report object and call the render method on it. The next most important part is to pass the arguments you wish to pass to it.

Once you have done this you can access those values by key name in the qweb report. I understand that there are a lot of concepts and contexts and blah blah blahs to digest for a new Odoo developer. I will try to provide an example. And do my best to keep it as simple as possible. If it makes you feel any better I spent the better part of an afternoon the first time I tried to do this with a custom report.

You will need to define a AbstractModel class for your report. Include this is a `.py` file which is included in `__init__.py`. You probably will want some logging just to see what is happening unless you are so lucky to have it work first time.

I was not.

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class YourReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.your_addon.report_template_id'

    @api.multi
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        _logger.info("RUNNING REPORT")
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('your_addon.report_template_id')
        docs = self.env['your_addon.your_model'].search([('something','=','something')])   
        docargs = {
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': docs,
        }
        return report_obj.render('your_addon.report_template_id', docargs)
```

In the class above we override the `render_html` method. The report model method `_get_report_from_name` is just a method which returns the report object for a named report. You can replace this with any `odoo orm` that returns a browse object for a report.

You must then create the xml definition for your report.

```
<openerp>
  <data>
    <report
        id="report_template_id"
        model="your_addon.model"
        string="Report Title"
        name="your_addon.report_template_view"
        file="your_addon.report_template"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"/>

    <template id="report_template_view">
        <t t-call="report.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                <t>
                    <div class="page">
                        <t t-esc="doc.field_name"/>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

If you create a button in any model's form view that executes a method returning a report action the render_html function for your report will be called.

```
    @api.multi
    def print_report(self):
    return {
        'type' : 'ir.actions.report',
        'report_name': 'report_template_id'
        'datas': {
            'ids': [ self.id ],
            'model': 'your_addon.your_model'
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Philip Stack Tnx for description, I my example I want dispalay data from res.users is this correct code http://imgur.com/a/k6U0N What is different between  your_model in docs and report.model in docargs?

Comment: There is no difference. It should be the same model. `report.model` is the `model` attribute of the report browse object. Some of this I adapted from odoo's documentation. In reality you could just use `your_addon.your_model`

Comment: I think if your model is Anastasio.res.users then the doc_model should be the same. You should be able to test the validity of your model name by using erppeek or even odoo shell. These are great tools. You can test your methods in the odoo shell interactively which will tell you if you are on the right track or not.

Comment: Start your server manually. Like this `./odoo.py shell -d database_name or in version 10 ./odoo-bin shell -d database_name

Comment: Then just start browsing records and executing commands like you dont have a care in the world.

Comment: Thanks for help but I can't generate report! Here is my source http://imgur.com/a/86Jry

Comment: I will take a look when I get a moment today.

Comment: In your report definition the model attribute. Remove your model name. As bizarre as that may seem. Just `report.report_template_id`.

Comment: @Philip Stack Sorry but I don't understand your last comment, In .xm file I'm change model name from report.test_ana.report_template_id  to report.report_template_id and get error report.report_template_id: (<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, KeyError(u'report.report_template_id',), <traceback object at 0x7fba80b69200>)

Comment: Also in render_html  im update model to report.report_template_id